# Date-Span in Event Filter

Tags: events

Want to provide an interface on my page to show filter based event data.

Haven't come across a proper working example to fetch event data by providing a date span. So it will be helpful if one could give few examples of querying on old event data.

Comment: Take a loot at my answer here http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/is-searching-data-stored-in-event-logs-prohibitively-slow/2195#2195

Comment: Thanks for sharing your post Debris, but I was looking for more query specific examples.